# EPiServer - how to search content in different EPiServer websites?

Tags: lucene.net, episerver

Greetings EPiServer gurus.

**Picture this scenario:**

*A customer has got two different EPiServer-sites. 
One internal and one external website.
The external is using EPiServer Find's REST API for search.
The internal is currently using a simple Search page which is based upon the Lucene indexer.*

The customer wants to be able to search both the *external* and *internal* site's content **INSIDE** the internal site. They are not keen on the idea of having to buy another EPiServer Find license to apply on the internal. So basically they want to be able to search the content of the external site while inside of the internal.

**What would be the proper approach in order to do this?**
Any suggestions appreciated.

/ChrisRun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. EPiServer Find support multi site setup but requires them to be hosted in the same solution. EPiServer constructed the indexing job in such way that it **clears the entire Find index**, this means that if you have the same Find index on two different machines they will erase each others indexes, effectively you'll only have the results from the most recently indexed site.

We've discussed this with EPiServer on changing this pattern to only allow an indexer to erase posts with `siteId's` available to the solution running the index job. However, no luck so far, instead we rely on hackish solutions :)

So, what you are asking is possible with a bit of coding, reflect the built-in indexer and ensure the `ReindexTarget` are scoped correctly (the code is easy to understand). When done this indexing job needs to be used on both the internal and external environment and the original job needs to be removed.

There's no need for filtering in your internal environment but in the external environment you'll have to ensure only external results are posted. If your results include anything else than pages you cannot filter on `siteId` since global items (like files and images) doesn't have any siteId. We've solved this with a url-filter like the one below.

```
private static FilterBuilder<ISearchContent> SiteFilterBuilder
{
    get
    {
        var filter = SearchClient.Instance.BuildFilter<ISearchContent>();
        filter = filter.Or(x => x.SearchHitUrl.Prefix(EPiServer.Web.SiteDefinition.Current.SiteUrl.AbsoluteUri));
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Implement

```
var query = SearchClient.Instance.UnifiedSearch(Language.Swedish)
    .For(searchQuery.Query)
    .AndInField(x => x.SearchCategories)
    .UsingSynonyms()
    .OrFilter(SiteFilterBuilder) // will scope to this site
    .ApplyBestBets()
    .Track()
    .TermsFacetFor(x => x.SearchSection)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I can see multiple risks involved in adding the public Find index to the internal site - especially if you don't want it two-way (i.e. index the internal site in the same Find index).

**One approach could be to add a search endpoint to the public website**, which the internal website invokes to do searches.

Basically that endpoint (for example a controller action method) would perform a search using Find (this would happen inside the public web application) and then return the result to the internal website.

Technically, only the public website would use Find - but results would be available to the internal website.